# React how to make POST request in For Loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, post, fetch

I have the following function which aims to delete all the elements in a table.
The key field of each row is stored in `rowKeys` with current contents `["www.google.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.facebook.com"]`

```
async onAfterDeleteRow(rowKeys) {
    for(let i = 0; i < rowKeys.length; i++){
        console.log(rowKeys.length);  //3
        console.log(rowKeys[i]);  //www.google.com

        this.setState({
            deleting: true,
            jsonBefore: this.state.json
        });

        console.log("About to post");  //About to post

        const response = await
            fetch('/delete-cert', {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },

                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({deletedCert: rowKeys[i]})
            });

        console.log("Post done");

        const body = await response.text();
        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
    }

    console.log("Left For Loop");
}
```

The following 3 lines are printed to the console:

```
3  
www.google.com  
About to post
```

But it does NOT print the 2 lines:

```
Post done  
Left For Loop
```

It successfully deletes `www.google.com` but not the next 2 items in the array, any idea why this iteration isn't working?

Comment: start by wrapping those awaits in a try catch block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the fetch does not resolve or throws an error. Since you await this statement the execution of the other code will never happen.

A better thing to do is to trigger all the requests and wait until all of them are finished (see [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)).

```js
async onAfterDeleteRow(rowKeys) {
    // a list of all request promises
    let requests = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < rowKeys.length; i++){
        console.log(rowKeys.length);  //3
        console.log(rowKeys[i]);  //www.google.com

        this.setState({
            deleting: true,
            jsonBefore: Kthis.state.json
        });

        requests.push( 
            fetch('/delete-cert', {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },

                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({deletedCert: rowKeys[i]})
            }).then(async (response)=>{
                const body = await response.text();
                if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
                // if everything is fine resiolve to true or for example your body content
                return Promise.resolve(true);
            }).catch((e)=>{
                // if we encounter an error resolve to false
                console.error('there was an error:', e.message)
                return Promise.resolve(false);
            })
        )
    }
    console.log("Left For Loop");

    // wait until all requests are done!
    await Promise.all(requests).then((results)=>{
        // here we have all the results
        console.log('all requests finished!', results);
        for(let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++){
          console.log(i, 'request resultet in', results[i]);
        }
    })
}
```